# Filterable dropdown getting id

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, dropdown

I have to get the selected option's id.

This way returns always the first id, it returns "1" :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var skills = document.getElementById('toto');
  var skillId = skills.getAttribute('data-id');
  console.log(skillId);
}
```

```html
<label>
    Skills :
    <input id="inputTest" name='skill' list='skills'>
        <datalist id='skills'>
            <select> 
                 <option id="toto" data-id="1">HTML</option>
                 <option id="toto" data-id="2">Jquery</option>
                 <option id="toto" data-id="3">CSS</option>
            </select>
        </datalist>
    </label>

<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="myFunction()"> Clickhere </button>
```

This way doesnt works , it returns "null" :

```
<label>
Skills :
<input id="inputTest" name='skill' list='skills'>
    <datalist id='skills'>
        <select>
         <div id="toto">
            <option data-id="1">HTML</option>
            <option data-id="2">Jquery</option>
            <option data-id="3">CSS</option>
         </div>
        </select>
    </datalist>
</label>

<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="myFunction()"> Clickhere </button>

<script>
    function myFunction(){
    var skills = document.getElementById('toto');
    var skillId = skills.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log(skillId); 
    }
</script>
```

The following way doesnt works too :

```
...
<datalist id='skills'>
...
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
        var skills = document.getElementById('skills');
        var skillId = skills.getAttribute('data-id');
        console.log(skillId); 
        }
    </script>
```

And If i put the id on the  , it doesnt works too..

the `getAttribute()` method is inevitably in the same `<div></div>` that `getElementById()` method ?

I just want to understand the correct functioning..

There he another way to do that without datalist ? Because "the datalist tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari".

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `map()` to get the option by matching the text:

```js
function myFunction(){
  var skills = document.getElementById('inputTest');
  var allOption = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#skills option'));
  var selected = allOption.filter(o => o.textContent == skills.value).map(el => el.getAttribute('data-id'))[0];
  console.log(selected); 
}
```

```html
<label>
Skills :
<input id="inputTest" name='skill' list='skills'>
    <datalist id='skills'>
        <option data-id="1">HTML</option>
        <option data-id="2">Jquery</option>
        <option data-id="3">CSS</option>
    </datalist>
</label>

<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="myFunction()"> Clickhere </button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code always return the first id : "1"

Comment: it works great @Mamun, thanks a lot. It seems to be a little bit complex. There must be a simpler way to answer this question, no ?

Answer (score 1):

@Mamun, it works like a charm, by the way i have found another way to do it with Jquery :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button1').click(function()
    {
        var value = $('#inputTest').val();
        console.log(($('#skills [value="' + value + '"]').data('value')));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
Skills :
<input id="inputTest" name='skill' list='skills'>
    <datalist id='skills'>
        <option value="HTML" data-value="1"></option>
        <option value="CSS" data-value="2"></option>
        <option value="Jquery" data-value="3"></option>
        <option value="Java" data-value="4"></option>
    </datalist>
</label>

<button type="button" id="button1"> Clickhere </button>
```

I hope it helps you out too.